# How to exclude properties from NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, macos, core-data

I'm using CoreData in my application and depend on the NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification. I have already subclassed NSManagedObject for all my Entities and created the properties and @dynamic accessors. Is it possible to exclude some properties of specific entities from the notification? If so, how would I do it? :-)

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You want to change a property without firing a `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent the context change notification from firing for some attribute of some entity instance, but you *can* get information about the nature of the changes and respond to that instead.

Use [notification userInfo] to get a dictionary that contains lists of the changed objects based on the general type of change (inserted, updated, deleted). Example (pulled from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660280/nsmanagedobjectcontextobjectsdidchangenotification-userinfo-dictionary)):

```
NSSet * deletedObjects = [userInfoDictionary objectForKey:NSDeletedObjectsKey];
```

You can then ask the managed objects for their [-changedValues](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html) and take appropriate action if the keys of the returned dictionary contain (or don't) the interesting attribute keys.